# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP в long

Tags: java

К примеру есть дата, которая была сделана с помощью `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` в `mysql` -> `String date = "2017-12-20 16:49:31";`
Мне нужно её преобразовать в то, из чего можно вытащить время UNIX того момента, когда произошёл слепок этой даты. Рылся на зарубежном форуме, но там разбирают другой формат даты, не знаю куда копать дальше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решён, как всегда, только спрошу и нахожу решение! 
Документация - сила!

```
String date = "2017-12-20 16:49:31";
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(date);
System.out.println(timestamp.getTime());
```